# Show histogram bar outline

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

```
df3['a'].plot.hist(color='blue',xlim=(0,1))
```

I want to know how can it show the line in the histogram figure.
Make the top figure showed as bottom figure. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `edgecolor` argument to [`hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html).

```
df3['a'].plot.hist(color='blue',
                   edgecolor='black',
                   xlim=(0,1))
```

---

**Demo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(vals=np.random.normal(size=100)))

df.plot.hist(edgecolor='black')
```

[image: demo]